# "adding variable into mysqli"

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote the code below. When I pass `$cat_title` in myslqi and i print $query it runs the query but in mysql table `cat_title` field is empty.

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];
    echo "this is cat_title: ".$cat_title."<br>";
    if($cat_title ="" ){
        echo "title shouldn't be empty";
    }
    else{
        echo $cat_title."this is cat_tiltel";
        $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) ";
        $query .= "VALUE('{$cat_title}') ";
        echo $query;
        $create_category_query = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
        if(!$create_category_query){
            die("QUERY FAILD".mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        header("location:categories.php");
    }

}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat-title">category title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name ="cat_title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  class =  type="submit" name ="submit" value ="Add category">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you open the connection?

Comment: @Dharman I made it in another file and I include it in first line of file the command works but problem is that the field is empty!

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: `if($cat_title ="" ){` sets `$cat_title` to a blank string. Use `==` for [comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Format code, fix grammar.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo error. Please write "VALUES". You have written just VALUE.

Plese try to use below sintex.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(column_1,column_2,...) VALUES (value_1,value_2,...);
```

Comment: Can you please print the query and run it in your database? Is it works?

Comment: `INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) VALUES('')` , this shows when I print `$query` but I wonder why it pass `$cat_title` null in query . I print `$cat_title~ lonely and it shows its real value (not empty).

Comment: You need to print `$cat_title` line by line and debug the code. You need to check that when the value going to blank.

Comment: goddamn mistake!  in if statement I wrote assignment (`=`) but I had to write comparison(`==`)!

Comment: Okay! Yeah i saw that! All the best :)